# How to defer multiple stylesheets with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is very close to what I need to do, I just need a little help. So firstly what I currently have is something that looks like below

And I want to know if there is a way to either 1) move that script to a .js file and execute it for each file I want loaded or 2) to use that same script just once in the html but be able to add multiple stylesheets to it.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style4.css">
  </noscript>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- Content -->


  <script defer>
    var cb = function() {
      var l = document.createElement("link");
      l.rel = "stylesheet";
      l.href = "style1.css";
      var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
    };
    var raf =
      requestAnimationFrame ||
      mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      msRequestAnimationFrame;
    if (raf) raf(cb);
    else window.addEventListener("load", cb);
  </script>

  <script defer>
    var cb = function() {
      var l = document.createElement("link");
      l.rel = "stylesheet";
      l.href = "style2.css";
      var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
    };
    var raf =
      requestAnimationFrame ||
      mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      msRequestAnimationFrame;
    if (raf) raf(cb);
    else window.addEventListener("load", cb);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just pass the name of your stylesheet into a (singular) function

Comment: You're inserting the newly created `link` element before the `head`. It should be appended to the `head`. `h.appendChild(l)`. You could just wrap it in a function that takes the path to the stylesheet and call that function as many times as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the first 2 comments (from Heretic Monkey and Liam) as a bit of a guide and came up with this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <noscript>
      <link rel="stylesheet" src="style1.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" src="style2.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" src="style3.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" src="style4.css" />
    </noscript>
  </head>

  <body>
      
    <!-- Content -->

    <script async>
      var cb = function () { 

        var a = document.createElement("link");
        a.rel = "stylesheet";
        a.href = "style1.css";

        var b = document.createElement("link");
        b.rel = "stylesheet";
        b.href = "style2.css";

        var c = document.createElement("link");
        c.rel = "stylesheet";
        c.href = "style3.css";

        var d = document.createElement("link");
        d.rel = "stylesheet";
        d.href = "style4.css";

        var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

        h.appendChild(a);
        h.appendChild(b);
        h.appendChild(c);
        h.appendChild(d);
      };

      var raf =
        requestAnimationFrame ||
        mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(cb);
      else window.addEventListener("load", cb);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did change it to async instead of defer. And I'm not to great with JavaScript so I'm not sure how you would add that to a separate .js file and call it which would probably make the code look a lot better, but this worked for what I wanted.